# Python - HTML - Request de un Select o Combo

Tags: html, python, flask

Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme, el error creo que lo tengo en una sola línea de código. El problema lo estoy teniendo al tratar de recoger un valor con Python-Flask desde un select (o combo) de HTML que es seleccionado por el usuario. Al intentar imprimirlo de vuelta en el HTML, no recibo el texto que se seleccionó *(en este caso psi / bar)*. Transcribo lo que tengo en ambos archivos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`index.html:`

```
<html>
  <body>
  <form action="/" method="post" id="formP" autocomplete="off">  
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="presion" placeholder="Introduzca presión" aria-label="Presión...">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <label class="input-group-text" for="unit_p">Unidades:</label>
      </div>
      <select class="custom-select" name="unit_p">
        <option selected>Seleccione unidades...</option>
        <option value="1">psi</option> <!-- aca puede estar faltando algo
        <option value="2">bar</option> <!-- aca puede estar faltando algo
      </select>   
      <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
  </form>
  <h2 id="message"></h2>
 <script>
    document.querySelector("#formP").addEventListener("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        form = new FormData(this)
        fetch(this.action, {
          method: 'post',
          body: form
        })
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(resp => {
          const el = document.querySelector("#message")
            el.innerHTML = 'La presión es ' + resp.presion + ' en unidades ' + resp.unit_p      
        })
    });
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`index.py:`

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def miFunc():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template("index.html")
    else:
        # creo un dict para guardar valor de presión y unidades de presión seleccionadas
        payload = {
            'presion': 0,
            'unit_p': 0
        }

        presion = request.form.get('presion')
        unit_p = request.form.get('unit_p') # Acá está el error
        payload['presion'] = presion
        payload['unit_p'] = unit_p
        return payload

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

no se si ya lo resolviste, pero debes tomar el valor .value del select.
Además, elimina las propiedades value de los options.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).